# Tortoise SVN - moving whole project to a folder

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am having a huge problem with this.

I want to take my whole project from the **root** folder, and move it to the **root/webUI** folder.

What I have done seems simple, but it's not working. I simply made the new **root/webUI** folders, selected everything else in the **root** folder, and right-click dragged it into the new folder. I then elected to **SVN Move Versions Item(s) Here** which is all well and good, everything shows up in local drive just fine.

Then I go to commit the new changes, everything seems to work, but only the upper level folders are uploaded, none of the contents inside are added at all.  Is there any way to force a full update?  It seems that SVN feels it is up-to-date, even though the files in the repository are absent in relation to my project.

Please let me know if this does not make sense.

Comment: Copy/paste "svn status" command output in the root folder of your repo, so we can see the details.

Comment: `only the upper level folders are uploaded`: why do you mean exactly by uploaded? Normally you will only see a change in the root files and directories, as they are deleted and copied to the webUI directory (SVN's way of moving is delete+copy). You will not see anything related to the subdirectory contents in your log, that's normal. What is the content of your repository and local copy? Do they match? If not, we need more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made several times the experience that the Subversion command line interface is more reliable that TurtoiseSVN for various move manipulations.

Before loosing your patience with TurtoiseSVN, I would first try with the `svn move` command. See the [Subversion documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re18.html) for more info.

Comment: I know, the question was about "TurtoiseSVN" but I think you should have several tools in your toolbox. If a tool doesn't do what you want (especially if it's a one time job), just take another took and be done with it. Nothing wrong with TurtoiseSVN but sometimes other tool are better at solving a particular problem.

Answer (score 2):

This process should be a two commit process.

1. Create the destination folder in the
   root folder of your working copy.

   - Commit the changes (ie. Adding new
     folder).
   - Select all other files you
     want to move into the new folder.
   - Right click and hold the selected
     group of files.
   - Drag the your cursor
     to the new folder, release.
   - In the menu that results, select SVN Move.
   - Commit your changes

Comment: Alternatively instead of step 2, u can just do a folder add, which is local